# Relation pairs, which element has a relation to the other?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

In pairs of elements, like for instance (2,1), is it 2 that relates to 1 (2R1) or is it 1 that relates to 2 (1R2)?

Comment: The former, but by convention. If you wanted to do the latter, it would have no impact on math, just as long as you were consistent.

Comment: So the first number has a relation to the later subsequent number?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.